# How to save multiple window arrangement in emacs?

Tags: emacs

GNU Emacs 23.1, Windows XP.
I usually split a frame to four windows. How can I save this arrangement and restore at my next session?

Commands desktop-save and desktop-change-dir don't remember what I want.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I really like [Policy Switch](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PolicySwitch).  The UI is fairly involved, but that's a typical trade-off for flexibility.  I find the above-linked wiki page a bit cryptic as well.  But just read the documentation in the source itself.  (And use menu-bar-mode to start off).

Answer (score 1):

The package [layout-restore](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LayoutRestore) does what you want.

Comment: Thanks. Not quite right what I want. But I'm trying some other packages in the same site.